# Return a whole object based on just one property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm writing a program that schedules assignments with a number of hours (quota) to meet by the deadline (dueDate). It is based on an array of assignment objects.

```js
var assignments = [m1 = {
    moduleCode: "346",
    moduleName: "Computer Science",
    quota: 100,
    dueDate: "2019-12-12"
  }, m2 = {
    moduleCode: "360",
    moduleName: "Maths",
    quota: 200,
    dueDate: "2020-05-01"
  }];
```

I'm writing a functions to retrieve an object based on certain parameters, e.g. the one with the highest number of hours, but I want to return the object as a whole, instead of just the property.

```
function getHighestWorkload(assignments) {
  let highestQuota = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<assignments.length; i++) {
    if(assignments[i].quota > highestQuota) {
      highestQuota = assignments[i].quota;
    }
  }
  // Get the entire assignment object based on its quota 
}
```

Is there a way to return the entire object based on its parameter? 
Thank you.

Comment: Store the the object that has the highest quota, not the `highestQuota` value itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by sorting the array `desc` order then grab the first index value.

```js
var assignments = [
  {
    moduleCode: "346",
    moduleName: "Computer Science",
    quota: 100,
    dueDate: "2019-12-12"
  },
  {
    moduleCode: "360",
    moduleName: "Maths",
    quota: 200,
    dueDate: "2020-05-01"
  }
];

assignments.sort((a,b) => b.quota - a.quota);

console.log(assignments[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning the object property value to `highestQuota` with `highestQuota = assignments[i].quota;`. If you want `highestQuota` to be assigned an object, it needs to be initialized as an object first, and then you need to add the entire assignments object, and not just it's value.

```
let highestQuota = {} 
highestQuota = assignments[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var assignments = [m1 = {
    moduleCode: "346",
    moduleName: "Computer Science",
    quota: 100,
    dueDate: "2019-12-12"
  }, m2 = {
    moduleCode: "360",
    moduleName: "Maths",
    quota: 200,
    dueDate: "2020-05-01"
  }];


function getHighestWorkload(assignments) {
  let highestQuota = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<assignments.length; i++) {  
    if(assignments[i].quota > highestQuota) {
      highestQuota = assignments[i].quota;
      var myObject = assignments[i]
    }
  }
  return myObject;
 }

console.log(getHighestWorkload(assignments));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var assignments = [m1 = {
    moduleCode: "346",
    moduleName: "Computer Science",
    quota: 100,
    dueDate: "2019-12-12"
  }, m2 = {
    moduleCode: "360",
    moduleName: "Maths",
    quota: 200,
    dueDate: "2020-05-01"
  }];
  
  let highestQuotaObj=assignments[0]
  assignments.forEach(obj=>{
  highestQuotaObj=highestQuotaObj.quota>obj.quota?highestQuotaObj:obj;
  })
  console.log(highestQuotaObj)
```